# How to use dynamic grammar in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I want to bind the datasource to GridView,but it doesn't work,because the datasource is dynamic,Who can give me a hand?
Thank you!

/***********c#************/

```
List<dynamic> dyList = new List<dynamic>();
dynamic info1 = new ExpandoObject();
info1.FFID = 1;
info1.Name = "Bill1";

dynamic info2 = new ExpandoObject();
info2.FFID = 2;
info2.Name = "Bill2";

dyList.Add(info1);
dyList.Add(info2);

Repeater1.DataSource = dyList;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

/***********aspx****************/

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("FFID") %> <%# Eval("Name") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Can't find FFid and Name,Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps if you cast the item to `dynamic`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <%# ((dynamic)Container.DataItem).FFID %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Or to `IDictionary<string, object>`. (`ExpandoObject` implements that)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <%# ((IDictionary<string, object>)Container.DataItem)["FFID"] %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```